# How to set characters limit in UILabel Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, character

How to set 200 characters limit in UILabel Xcode?

Please see attached the screenshot.
[image]

I want to display at least 200 characters limit.

Comment: @ Anne For which label you want to set characters limit ?..And secondly user cannot give input to UILabel, so why do you want to set limit for a label ?

Comment: You have to reduce the font size / increase the number of lines of the UILabel.

Comment: I did. But it doesn't work. Reduce the font size + increase the number of lines of the UILabel using storyboard. The word, God can open doors in your life that you never thought would open. Trust his plan, in his timing he will open the right doors. It should be shown in our App. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the UILabel to 200 character and than Truncate the label

```
NSString *tempstring = "LabelValue";
if ([tempstring length] > 200) {
    NSRange range = [tempstring rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:(NSRange){0, 200}];
    tempstring = [tempstring substringWithRange:range];
    tempstring = [tempstring stringByAppendingString:@"…"];
}
Label.text = tempstring;
```

Comment: Ok. let me know :)

Comment: Why don't you just set the text of the label to itself if its length exceeds 200 instead of setting its subset?

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0

You can limit your text in label using

```
 var textOnLabel = "your text"
    if(textOnLabel.characters.count > 200){

         textOnLabel = textOnLabel[textOnLabel.startIndex..<textOnLabel.index(textOnLabel.startIndex, offsetBy: 200)]
    }

    yourLabel.text = textOnLabel
```

But remember that you may not be able to see multiple lines on your Label due to some of these reasons

- 1. Your label height is fixed
- 2. Your cell is not growing

Answer could be more specific if you give some details that how you have implemented your cell (AutoLayout) or manually increasing cell height using heightForRowAtIndexpath

Comment: I see. How about in Objective-C? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with to set number of lines 0 of UILabel.

If your Label will not showing complete text then you have to reduce the font or increase height of label if possible space exist.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4:

```
yourLabel.text = yourString.prefix(200)
```